# Generator polynomial creates a 127 bit sequence

Tags: coding-theory, binary

I have been reading a paper that states that a generator polynomial

$$ G(D)= 1+ D^4+D^7$$ creates a 127 bit sequence which is as follows

00001110 11110010 11001001 00000010 00100110
00101110 10110110 00001100 11010100 11100111 10110100 00101010 11111010
01010001 10111000 1111111

if the initial state used is 1111111.

I don't understand why this is the case

My thoughts are as follows:

$G(D)= 1+ D^4+D^7 $---->  in time domain is equivalent to $1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1$. How can I use the initial state to generate the 127 bit sequence. DO I perform a convolution between two sequences?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The terms you need to search for are _linear feedback shift register, maximal-length sequence, PN sequence, pseudonoise sequence, linear recurrence_ etc.

Comment: 127 bit sequence in question is the list of codewords that represent some encoded data. Codewords are products of the data word and generator polynomial. To tell more you have to provide the length of the code used with this generator and encoded data.

Comment: Thanks, In this case, the length of the code i.e the input to the generator is 7 bit. The initial state 0000000@hOff

Comment: Tyrone, I'm sure that's not the initial state. If you put an LFSR to all zeros state initially, it stays there. Nevertheless, the feedback polynomial is primitive, so you do get an $m$-sequence: a sequence of bits repeating with a period of length 127 such that all 7 bit combinations occur as conseuctive bits (with the exception 7 zeros).

Comment: I have attached part of the paragraph of the book I have go tthis example from. @JyrkiLahtonen Please let me know what you think

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen do you have any comments for me to understand how to get the sequence?

Comment: Tyrone: I think that the polynomial $G(D)$ is used as a recurrence relation:
$$s_{n+7}+s_{n+4}+s_n=0$$ for all $n$. From this we can solve
$$s_{n+7}=s_{n+4}+s_n.$$ So if the initial segment is
$s_0=s_1=s_2=\cdots=s_6=1$, then $s_7=s_4+s_0=0$, $s_8=s_5+s_1=0$, $s_9=s_6+s_2=0$, $s_{10}=s_7+s_3=1$ et cetera, which seems to fit (assuming that the earliest bits of the sequence are at the right end). I always recheck little-endian vs. big-endian details here, because I tend to forget them. Also, sometimes people use reciprocal polynomials. I won't get into details, but those work equally well.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for posting an easily googlable example of a 127-bit LFSR m-sequence!

Answer (score 4):

My few cents here. The shift register circuit implementation (using the external feedback addition aka Fibonacci) will look something like this. 
[Shift register sequence with generator $p(x)=1+x^2+x^7$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPNAP.png)
[image]

I find it easier to use the matrix algebra to analyze this. For e.g., using the Frobenius companion matrix $M$, corresponding to the given generator polynomial $\displaystyle p(x)=x^{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{p_{i} x^{i}}$. The companion matrix is constructed as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
M &=& \begin{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \bf{0}_{(n-1)\times 1} && \mathbb{I}_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} \end{pmatrix} \\  p \end{bmatrix} \\
&=&  \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
                                   0 & 0 &1 & \ldots &  \ldots & 0 \\
                                   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots \\
                                     0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 \\
                                   0 & 0 & 0& \ldots & 0 & 1 \\
                                  p_{0} & p_{1} &p_{2} & \ldots & p_{n-2} & p_{n-1} 
                                   \end{bmatrix}, 
\end{eqnarray*}

Where $p= \begin{bmatrix} p_{0} & p_{1} & p_{2} & \ldots & p_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$.
With every clock tick (i.e., every shift of the shift register), the state evolve through the linear mapping (all operations in field $\mathbb{F}_{2}$),
\begin{eqnarray*}
S(k+1) &=& M S(k),
\end{eqnarray*}

Here, $S(k)=\begin{bmatrix} s_{0}(k) & s_{1} (k) & s_{2} (k) & \ldots & s_{n-1}(k)  \end{bmatrix}$ is the state vector. In the beginning (the initial seed), i.e., at $k=0$, starts with $S(0)=\begin{bmatrix} s_{0}(0) & s_{1} (0) & s_{2} (0) & \ldots & s_{n-1}(0)  \end{bmatrix}$. It then follow,

\begin{eqnarray*}
S(k) &=&  M^{k} S(0) \\
       &=&  \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 &0\\
                                   0 & 0 &1 & \ldots &  \ldots & 0 &0 \\
                                   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
                                     0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0& 0 \\
                                   0 & 0 & 0& \ldots & 0 & 1 &0\\
                                   0 & 0 & 0& \ldots & 0 & 0 &1\\
                                   p_{0} & p_{1} &p_{2} & \ldots &  p_{n-3}  & p_{n-2} & p_{n-1} 
                                   \end{bmatrix}^{k} \begin{bmatrix} s_{0}(0) \\ s_{1} (0) \\ s_{2} (0) \\  \vdots \\ s_{n-3}(0) \\ s_{n-2}(0)  \\ s_{n-1}(0)  \end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

In the running example, $p(x)=x^7+x^{4}+1$ and $n=7$. With the initial seed $S(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 \end{bmatrix}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
S(k) &=&  \begin{pmatrix}  0 &1 & 0 &0& 0 & 0  &0\\
                                   0 & 0 &1 &0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
                                    0 & 0 & 0 &1& 0& 0 &0\\
                                     0 & 0 & 0 &0& 1 & 0 &0\\
                                   0 & 0 & 0&0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
                                  0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\
                                   1 & 0 &0 &1 & 0 & 0 &0
                                   \end{pmatrix}^{k}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \\ 1  \\ 1  \\ 1  \\ 1   \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}       
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0  1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1  0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1   0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1  0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0 \\
     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1  1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0   0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0   0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1  0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0   0     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1 \\
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1  0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0   0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0   1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0   0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0   0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1 \\
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0   0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0   1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1  1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0   0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0   1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1 \\
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0  1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1   0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1   0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0   0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1   1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1 \\
     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1   0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0   1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0   1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0    1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1    0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1\\
{\color{blue} {1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0  0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1    1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1   0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1  0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0   1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1}}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

It takes 7 clocks to flush out the initial sequence (although it will eventually get there, because of the periodicity). The output  tapped at the output of the last cell is the sequence in question (and of interest, shown in blue).
[image]

[The state matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjw7L.png)